# Hibernate many-to-any delete with annotations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, many-to-many

I have a problem deleting with hibernate. I have tryed a lot of "solutions" but they haven't worked. I want to delete a team (equipo) without deleting the tournament (campeonato)

So, I have this ER

```
Equipo   -->    Equipo_Campeonato  <--  Campeonato
 id               Equipo                 id
 nombre           Campeonato             nombre
```

My entities are:

Table Equipo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="equipo"
    ,catalog="sistemafutbol"
)
public class Equipo  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String nombre;
 private Set<Campeonato> campeonatos = new HashSet<Campeonato>(0);

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="equipoxcampeonaato", catalog="sistemafutbol", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="Equipo", nullable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns =      { 
    @JoinColumn(name="Campeonato", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
public Set<Campeonato> getCampeonatos() {...
```

Tabla Campeonato

```
Entity
@Table(name="campeonato"
    ,catalog="sistemafutbol"
)
public class Campeonato  implements java.io.Serializable {


   private Integer id;
   private String nombre;
   private Set<Equipo> equipos = new HashSet<Equipo>(0);

   @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="equipoxcampeonaato", catalog="sistemafutbol", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="Campeonato", nullable=false, updatable=false) },  inverseJoinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="Equipo", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
     public Set<Equipo> getEquipos() {...
```

And the code with I've been trying to do it is:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
equipo.getCampeonatos().remove(campeonato);
campeonato.getEquipos().remove(equipo);
session.delete(equipo); // or session.merge(equipo); or session.saveOrUpdate(equipo);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

So I hope you can help me.

UPDATE

This is the code that  danny.lesnik tell me integrated to my code.

```
Campeonato campeonato = ControladorCampeonato.obtenCampeonato(idCampeonato);
//this is where I get the tournament
    if(listaEquiposSeleccionados.length>0){
        for(int i=0;i<listaEquiposSeleccionados.length;i++){
            int idEquipo = listaEquiposSeleccionados[i].getId().intValue();
            Equipo equipo= ControladorEquipo.obtenEquipo(idEquipo);            
            this is where I get the team.
            try{
                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                campeonato.getEquipos().remove(equipo);
                session.update(campeonato);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                listaEquiposAgregados.add(equipo);
            }
```

I'm doing a web page where I select a tournament and I can select multiple teams. I was debuging and the exception is right in the line session.update(campeonato); the exception was "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions". :S
SOLUTION by [danny-lesnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225396/danny-lesnik)

```
if(listaEquiposSeleccionados.length>0){            
        for(int i=0;i<listaEquiposSeleccionados.length;i++){
            int idEquipo = listaEquiposSeleccionados[i].getId().intValue();
                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                Equipo equipo= (Equipo)session.load(Equipo.class, idEquipo);
                Campeonato campeonato = (Campeonato)session.load(Campeonato.class, idCampeonato);
                campeonato.getEquipos().remove(equipo);
                session.update(campeonato);
                session.getTransaction().commit(); 
                session.close();
        }
}
```

I think the problem was load the "Campeonato" and the "Equipo" in differents sessions. Hope this help another people with the same problem.

Comment: what are you trying to do and what the problem is?

Comment: sorry for that, I want to delete a team (equipo) without deleting the tournament (campeonato)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to remove one special team from one special tournament. In your case it will be enough to remove a connection between it.

```
   String equepoId = "xxx"; // 
    String campeonatoId = "yyy";
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Campeonato campeonato = (Campeonato)session.load(Campeonato.class,campeonatoId);
    Equipo equipo = (Equipo)session.load(Equipo.Class,equapoId);
    campeonato.getEquipos().remove(equipo);
    session.update(campeonato);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So I think that migth work but i have a problem with that. I have to get the tournament by ID and the team by ID too. so hibernate throws an exception that I can't make an operation with two open sessions. I have that problem when I try to add a team to a tournamnet but I fix it with session.merge(). I'm gonna post the code in a different answer so you can see it and maybe helpme thanks!

Comment: hey thanks! that worked!!! I was doing the same thing just that I loaded Campeonato and Equipo in differents sessions, so maybe that was the problem. Thanks! you have no idea how much I thank you!

Comment: Ok, I accept the answer. Thanks a lot! and if there is no problem, hope you can help me with an other problem. Now I'm deleting on OneToMany but the child has two parents. If you can help me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437522/hibernate-one-to-many-deleting-with-annotations . if you can't thanks anyway for the help with this problem. ;)