# Hibernate one-to-many deleting with annotations

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a problem with deleting OneToMany and ManyToOne on hibernate. I guess the problem is that I have two parents for a single child. This is how I got it

```
Persona        Rol        Pais
 id             id         id
 name           name       name
 Pais
 Rol
```

As you can see, the person (persona) is related to the role (rol) and the country (pais).
My entities are like this:

Person

```
public class Persona  implements java.io.Serializable {
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Pais", nullable=false)
    public Pais getPais() {
       return this.pais;
    }

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="Rol", nullable=false)
   public Rol getRol() {
      return this.rol;
   }
```

Pais (Country)

```
public class Pais  implements java.io.Serializable {
   private Set<Persona> personas = new HashSet<Persona>(0);
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="pais", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
  public Set<Persona> getPersonas() {
    return this.personas;
```

Rol (role)

```
public class Rol  implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Set<Persona> personas = new HashSet<Persona>(0);

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="rol", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<Persona> getPersonas() {
      return this.personas;
    }
```

I'm trying to delete the Person and only the person so I think that I have to detach the country and the role first and then delete the person but that doesn't work. This is my code for deleting

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Persona p = (Persona)session.load(Persona.class, idPersona);
Pais pais = (Pais)session.load(Pais.class, p.getPais().getId()); //try to p.getPais();
rol rol = (Rol)session.load(Rol.class,p.getRol().getId()); //try to p.getRol();
pais.getPersonas().remove(p);
rol.getPersonas().remove(p);
p.setPais(null);
p.setRol(null);
session.update(pais);
session.update(rol);
session.delete(p);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Hope you can help me, this deleting thing in hibernate is freaking me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to delete Person. You can just delete it.

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Persona p = (Persona)session.load(Persona.class, idPersona);
session.delete(p);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: it doesn't matter the other relationships?? the parents I mean??

Comment: Nope, Think about it: all your foreign keys are in Person table. When you just delete Person it delete Role & Country foreign keys in the same row. That's it.

Comment: so that works...the problem wasn't the relationships or anything like that. The problem is that, like is a web page and i'm using java-primefaces it seems like the commandbutton doesn't call the method on the bean. I have two commands buttons and just one works fine (the one who adds a person), the one who deletes a person, just doesn't call the method. if you have any idea for this to happend, it will be very helpful. pd. I have a p:dataTable too and appears that's the problem. Thanks for the code, that helped me.